# N3 Pattern: Difference of 「～かわりに」、「～反面」、「～一方（で）」

Tags: grammar, jlpt

こんにちは！

ちょっと困ったことがありますが、誰か手伝ってくれるといいんですが・・・

Hello! I'm having a little confusion with this sentence from 新完全マスター３級・文法

In the explanation from the book, it is said that 「～反面」、「～一方」and 「～かわりに」means "on the other hand".

In this sentence:
「会長の山田さんは、実行力があるかわりに、深く考えることはしない。」

instead of using 「～かわりに」can we change it to 「～反面」or even 「～一方」？

～反面：
「会長の山田さんは、実行力がある反面、深く考えることはしない。」

～一方：
「会長の山田さんは、実行力がある一方で、深く考えることはしない。」

^ Are these sentences acceptable? Do they make sense? Are they even grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4):

All your sentences are valid and natural.

かわりに, 反面 and 一方（で）don't make any differences in your examples, but they could elsewhere.

**かわりに** literally means "instead", thus `A かわりに B` can mean either "do B instead of A" or "do B in return for doing A" (= A, on the other hand, B). But of course you can decide which from the context.

> 会長の山田さんは、実行力がある<sub>*A*</sub>かわりに、深く考えることはしない<sub>*B*</sub>。 (Has both sides)
>   会長の山田さんは、息子を社長にする<sub>*A*</sub>かわりに、外部から社長を招いた<sub>*B*</sub>。 (Only B, not A)

**反面** means "opposite side", like each side of the same coin. That means, in order to use this expression you must have not only the front (A) and the back (B) side, but also the common topic, or the "coin" (T).

> ○ 会長の山田さん<sub>*T*</sub>は、実行力がある<sub>*A*</sub>反面、深く考えることはしない<sub>*B*</sub>。
>   × 会長は実行力がある<sub>*A*</sub>反面、社長は意欲に乏しい<sub>*B*</sub>。 (Not sure what you're talking about)
>   ○ この会社<sub>*T*</sub>では、会長は実行力がある<sub>*A*</sub>反面、社長は意欲に乏しい<sub>*B*</sub>。

**一方（で）** can be used even when the former and the latter parts are not opposite. It could be someone's two separate strong points, or same action done by two different people etc.

> ○ 会長は経営に積極的に参加する一方で、社会活動にも力を注いでいる。
>   × 会長は経営に積極的に参加する反面、社会活動にも力を注いでいる。